# How to customize the angular material md-chips colour

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I want to customize the md-chip color randomly without using css style. Is there any attribute in the md-chip directive?

```
<md-chips placeholder="Add more tags here"
                         secondary-placeholder="Enter tags here"  ng-model="contact.contact.tags.attrVal"  md-on-add="contact.createTag(contact.contact)" md-on-remove="contact.removeTag(contact.contact)"></md-chips>
```

Comment: No. But you can probably use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-style. i.e

```
ng-style={background-color:'red'}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Issue 8692](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/8692) on Angular Material's github. It appears to be a known issue that is being worked on currently.